# VS2017 with Clang 6 keeps recompiling everything

Tags: visual-studio, clang, visual-studio-2017

I use Clang 6.0.0 (from the latest build of the Windows installer) with Visual Studio 2017 to build my project, and everything works fine except for one thing, it rebuilds every file every single time. Not only that, it even recompiles everything when no code changed at all and I merely use "Start Debugging" or "Start Without Debugging"! The .obj files are still there, but it doesn't seem to be reusing them, which of course is prohibitively slow!

This happens only when using Clang 6 with "LLVM-vs2014" set in my project, when I switch "Visual Studio 2017 (v141)" or "Visual Studio 2017 - Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (v141_clang_c2)" I don't have that problem, it only compiles what changed.

What could possibly cause this behaviour?

Edit: Maybe that's what the website means by "A 64-bit version is also available, but it doesn't integrate as well with Visual Studio."

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fafnir`.

https://github.com/kazatsuyu/fafnir

Visual Studio manages build dependencies using `.tlog` file, but it appears to generate wrong dependencies for recent `clang`. To fix it, `fafnir` uses API hooking to `SetFileInformationByHandle` through DLL injection.

Usage

1. Download the latest version from [the release page on GitHub](https://github.com/kazatsuyu/fafnir/releases)
2. Unzip it
3. Run `install.bat`
4. Specify the path of the directory of LLVM/clang
5. Specify `new_toolset_name` (in the form of `v[0-9]+_clang_.*`)

References

- [(Written in Japanese) Visual Studioでも最新のClangを使えるようにしたらキャッシュされていなかった](https://qiita.com/kazatsuyu/items/a1c65b3776481ba63da6)
- [(Written in Japanese) Visual Studioでも最新のClangが使いたい！](https://qiita.com/kazatsuyu/items/b85e97e38a25bc302054)